# I have Installed pybrain on python on ubuntu 12.04 but showing errors

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, pybrain

> I have install pybrain module inside python 2.7
>   I have installed pybrain but showing this error

```
import pybrain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bpa_pybrain1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pybrain
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .structure.__init__ import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .networks.__init__ import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/networks/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .swiping import SwipingNetwork
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/networks/swiping.py", line 127
    print(' ' * indent, k, end=' ')
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What was the command that raised this error?

Comment: in terminal import pybrain

Comment: How You install `PyBrain`? By `apt-get` or by `pip`? I guess by `apt-get`. If I have right, try to install by `pip`. Looks like You have modified package.

Comment: I have download form github
https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain

Comment: Unless you've modified the source code in pybrain, this would seem to be a bug in pybrain. Email the pybrain developers, letting them know what version of pybrain you have installed.

Comment: On GitHub version 0.3.1 don't have this line: https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/0.3.1/pybrain/structure/networks/swiping.py#L127 Do you have edited it manually?

Comment: The syntax error is on a call to the python 3 print function. Maybe you've installed a version that is only compatible with python 3?

Comment: I have installed both python2.7 and python3 both in my pc

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup  I have not modify any thing jest download and unzip and install

Comment: No version on GitHub with this line. Remove this version and try `pip install pybrain`

Comment: I have remove the packages 
and reinstall using pip install pybrain 
now working fine 
thank you TomaszJakubRup